# AWS connecting between instances within availability zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Few questions:

1. Are `us-east-1a`, `us-east-1b`, and `us-east-1d` considered one or three availability zone?
2. Say I have two instances within `us-east-1a`, one has a mongodb server, the other has a nodejs app. Do I need to add permissions for port 27017 (mongodb) to the security group for the app server to connect to the mongo server?
3. Same question as above, but say one server is in `us-east-1a` and the other is in `us-east-1b`. Do I need to modify the security group?
4. Would the VPC or Subnet ID have any effects on communication between instances?

**edit**

moved to [Server Faults](https://serverfault.com/questions/618537/aws-connecting-between-instances-within-availability-zone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) 3

2) Yes.

3) Yes

4) If you are using a VPC and trying to communicate outside of the VPC, you'll need to add a NAT box in that VPC. Then you'll obviously have to make security group changes. If you are trying to communicate inside of the VPC, it's easier since you won't need to create a NAT box, but you will still need to make security group changes. No matter what, you have to create security group changes if you want to communicate outside of ssh.

Side Note: You can use the instanceID in the security groups instead of IP addresses. This can be handy for a variety of reasons.